# Git adds untracked files that I dont recognize

Tags: windows, git, command-line-interface

I am using git cli, in windows 10, version:

```
2.33.1.windows.1
```

every time I want to commit, I check status before, and I see this:
[image: git status output in windows cmd]

what is:
**s]'** ?

google search did not bring me any helpful result, I try to add that to **.gitignore** but it still shows.

Comment: You could try `git clean -i` to remove it interactively. And observe if it still exists or gets created again. It looks like an unexpected product by some not well-organized command from a script.

Comment: *Git* didn't do that. An untracked file is one that's not in Git's index; it was probably created by errant keystrokes or non-Git software. At a guess, you  might have some sort of add-on software for your shell that has a bug in it that creates this file now and then.